# How can I easily plot 3D points in a simple Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d

***Short version:***

How can I quickly and easily plot 3D data points in X Y Z format in C# Windows forms?
For example, I could have 5 data points:

```
{ 1, 3, 4 },
{ 1, 2, 3 },
{ 2, 3, 3 },
{ 4, 4, 4 }, 
{ 4, 1, 2 }
```

How can I show this in 3D by adding the points one at a time?  I would like a working example.

**Lengthy / too much detail version:**

I've spent 15 minutes googlinghow to plot 3D points to a 3D engine to display them in C#, because I'm writing a program to create LED animations for my 4x4x4 cube. Not a single search result would show me how to do the task.

So far I have 64 Checkboxes, staggered to be slightly 3d. see here to see what I mean by *slightly*:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyphT.jpg

Since it is not true 3D (it is the best I could do since discovering windows forms doesn't support transparency on check boxes or image/layers), I want to have a real 3D engine re-generate the points so I can see the lights come up. (If you have a suggestion on how to make the 3D checkboxes more 3D like, I would love to hear it.  I used Gimp to create the 3D grid with different colors for each Z-axis layer.

Right now I have the IDs 1 through 64, but if I can plot points like {1, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 4} on a X Y Z plane, then I can rewrite the loop to write a lookup array or similar for each check that is checked.

Comment: whoever voted to close my question:  read the short version and tell me why this is too broad?  I like to give detail because then people don't have to ask "why would you want to do that?" or "what is your setup?" etc.

Comment: Have you considered something like an OpenGL drawing surface on a form?  Not too steep of a learning curve for what you are after.  Otherwise, you're in for a lot of pain.

Comment: Are you restricted to winforms? WPF provides a better framework for integrating UI controls in 3D environments. E.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49949/WPF-D-Tab-Carousel

Comment: Sure I would love to try openGL but I can't find a simple way to incorporate it.  Can you provide an example of adding 3D points to the surface? And how to import the library.  @carousel I will try wpf, I just never used it before, always windows forms.